# How to get resource map programmatically in JSF?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, resources

I want to access the resource map, not from my CCS file as in

```
background-image: url("#{resource['primefaces-supertheme:images/ui-icons_ffffff_0.png']}");
```

but from my bean. Is it possible with EL evaluation only?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The true Java variant would be [`Application#createResrouce()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceHandler.html#createResource%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and then [`Resource#getRequestPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Resource.html#getRequestPath%28%29):

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Resource resource = context.getApplication().getResourceHandler().createResource("images/ui-icons_ffffff_0.png", "primefaces-supertheme");
String url = resource.getRequestPath();
// ...
```

Note that you could just evaluate EL programmatically. You can use [`Application#evaluateExpressionGet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#evaluateExpressionGet%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) for this.

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
String url = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{resource['primefaces-supertheme:images/ui-icons_ffffff_0.png']}", String.class);
// ...
```

If you happen to use JSF utility library OmniFaces, this can be simplified via [`Faces`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/util/Faces.html) utility class as:

```
String url = Faces.evaluateExpressionGet("#{resource['primefaces-supertheme:images/ui-icons_ffffff_0.png']}");
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! All variants are useful. The simplest is with Omnifaces. I use Omnifaces btw. The Java variant is cool :-)